# mysql store sql file from mysqldump with different speed

Tags: mysql

I use mysqldump to sycronize data between two mysql server. The first time it took 3 hours to sycronize data, but after the first time, it took about 6 hours to do the same thing. After I restart the execute machine, the time it spent back to 3 hours.

The table type is innodb, the sql file size is about 150-200GB and about 300 million lines, I use crontab to execute the command, so every time the execute machine、mysql server are the same. The data size grows slowly.

Here is my mysqldump command:

```
mysqldump -h {host} -P {port} -u {user} -p{password} {db} {table} --single-transaction  --quick --no-create-info --replace --compact
```

Comment: Why not use myslq server to server data replication?  mysqldump doesn't sound like the right tool for the job.

Comment: @AleksG the mysql servers is controlled by another department, I only have read/write privileges. Besides, in my scenario, I only need to sycronize data once a day, 3hours are acceptable.